# Применить действие ко всем методам в классе

Tags: c#

Допустим, существует файл Keyboard.cs, в котором содержатся методы выполняющие нажатия (keypress, keydown и тд), нужно создать функцию, которая в качестве параметра принимала бы мой код, и вставляла бы его между BlockInput(true)  и BlockInput(false).

Например, я вызываю функцию:

```
SomeClass.Send(Keyboard.KeyPress(VK_RETURN));
```

Должен вызываться метод Send, который будет выполнять код:

```
BlockInput(true);
Keyboard.KeyPress(VK_RETURN); (функция которую я отправил в качестве аргумента)
BlockInput(false);
```

Это возможно? Если да, то можно примеры? Если нет, то как сделать что-то похожее?

Comment: Keyboard.cs это ваша сборка?

Comment: @A K нет, windowsinput simulator, это важно?

Answer (score 1):

Ну например:

```
public void Send(Action a)
{
    BlockInput(true);
    a();
    BlockInput(false);
}
```

и вызывать так:

```
SomeClass.Send(() => Keyboard.KeyPress(VK_RETURN));
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.

Comment: @Shader: Пожалуйста! Надеюсь, поможет.